# Генерирование шума заданной величины

Tags: интерполяция

Имеется код в маткаде, который может сгенерировать шум заданного уровня (в Вольтах) и отобразить график зависимости напряжения шума от времени (секунды). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Частично перевел часть кода на python, но не могу разобраться как правильно реализовать интерполяцию на python - то есть написать функции аналогичные **cspline** и **interp**.

Часы мучений и застрял на этом 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать данный код на пайтоне, как отобразить зависимость напряжения шума от времени?
PS. Python изучаю ровно один вечер. Спасибо за понимание

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вас интересует кубическая интерполяция в Пайтоне.

Судя по всему, аналогом функции `cspline` будет функция `scipy.interpolate.splprep`. По умолчанию она готовит данные для кубической интерполяции.

Собственно вычисляет интерполяцию функция `scipy.interpolate.splev`.

[Посмотрите тьюториал](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation).